# $ sign does not do anything in Sublime text (win10)

Tags: ide

I just started learning how to create a website and am watching tutorial videos. When they write $-sign it turns into green and you can see that it recognizes it, but in my case it does nothing, like it would be a random character (it remains white all the time and even if I write the same lines as it is in the video, I can not get the same results).

If you would like to see here it is:

```
$dayofweek = date("w");
echo "$dayofweek";
```

Comment: This is definitely an IDE issue and not PHP.  You should use the required and appropriate tags relevant to your question.

Comment: Do you have an opening PHP tag `<?php` before your code? If you check at the bottom right corner of the IDE, does it say "PHP" or something else? If it doesn't say "PHP", click on it and choose "PHP" from the list.

Comment: Yes I do have it and the bottom right corner shows that it is indeed php.